# mandrill logic if/else statement to provide a fallback option if condition not satisifed

Tags: if-statement, mandrill

I am trying to figure out mandrill conditional statements and have done a lot of reseach but cannot figure this out.

My logic looks like this:

```
*|IF:house=true|*
   House,  
*|END:IF|* 

*|IF:garden=true|*
    Garden,  
*|END:IF|*  

*|house!=true && garden=!true|*                                        
    House and Garden not included
*|END:IF|*
```

I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088996/conditional-content-in-mandrill-template?newreg=d8cd83c917a2426da47760fdfbacb375) answer would help me solve it but still cannot figure it out. I have tried all sorts of variations, but it is still not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm assuming you simply forgot the last `:IF` on the last condition when posting the question.

Regardless the format for the last condition is wrong. When you want to check two conditions simultaneously, the `:IF`s must be nested like so:

```
*|IF:MERGE1=x|*
    *|IF:MERGE2=y|*
          <div mc:edit="main"> 
                <p>content to display if both conditions are true</p>
           </div>
    *|END:IF|*
*|END:IF|*
```

Also, make sure you are passing the value for `house`and `garden` variables when they are false.

If when these two variables are false, the value isn't forwarded, then you need to use the `:IFNOT` tag:

```
*|IFNOT:MERGE|*
    content to display if MERGE is not provided
*|END:IF|*
```

So in your case the last condition would be:

```
*|IF:house!=true|* 
    *|IF:garden!=true|*                                        
        House and Garden not included
    *|END:IF|*
*|END:IF|*
```

Read more on mandrill conditional merge tags [here](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582527-Can-I-use-dynamic-or-conditional-merge-tags-).